Had there ever been an commercial jet aircraft accident caused solely by too many passengers?
I've been researching on a rather weird but interesting subject: had there ever been a plane crash or other accident that was caused solely by too much people crowded into an aircraft (not cargo, but humans, either passengers or crew)? Because I know that overweight cargo had caused many crashes but I've never seen or heard any crashes related to too much people being crowded into aircraft (although sometimes they are depicted in movies). Is there any such occasions? I mean, had human weight ever brought down an aircraft? Thanks for any answer!
Note: I'm looking for accidents involving either large jet aircraft (like Boeing 727, 737, 747, 767, 787..., or at the very least turboprops such as ATR-72), or accidents that involve at least 50 fatalities.

Just out of curiosity: the Concorde that crashed in Paris was also slightly overloaded (but that was not the direct nor the indirect cause of the incident)

Accidents do not have a single cause.

@Bianfable Thanks you for pointing that out. Boeing 727 and 737 are indeed narrow body aircraft, sorry for the mistake. I will edit my post to reflect this correction.

@AnonymousPhysicist Yes, I agree that accidents don't have a single cause, but there are usually at least one main contributing factor or the main cause. So I'm not looking for crashes caused by only overloading, but I'm looking for crashes that overloading was the main factor and no other main factors exist.

Any comment from downvoter? As always, please add a comment to inform me of any problems/mistakes/wrong behavior so that I can edit this post to improve and avoid these errors next time.

Any comments? I've got another downvote. Please do tell me how I can improve.

People usually fly with luggages, especially in widebody aircraft. Do luggages count as a factor ? Let's say you have military passengers with their 320Kgs equipment per person in the plane ?

@KarlStephen No, my question's intention is focused solely on the weight of people, not including any cargo or luggage. Sorry if my question isn't clear enough.

In that case, your only domain is "obscure flights" with no records whatsoever : Africa, possibly South America, Asia and Middle East (Hajj) in the 60s-80s era, decades ago when safety was less strict worldwide and people were flown in cargo planes, especially during war. You probably won't find any conclusive investigation, many tinted with politics where versions depends on who's talking. Documented airlifted people may have been conducted at slightly over MTOW, but all went pretty well. The C5 Galaxy crash during ops Babylift was caused by a structural failure, not weight.

I mean, the answer to your question is "NO, not a single one", as on AviationSE, we need/require documentation/sources. Opinion based thoughts says "we don't know for sure", but, for airliners with logged flights, there is not a single aircraft of the category you specified which crashed because of people weight. The downvotes (I didn't) are likely related to the fact any opinion-oriented answer to your question is invalid here, where, only an opinion-based answer could have either "yes" or "maybe".. As for the early ages of aviation, yes, pilot weight did bring many small attempts to fly down

@KarlStephen The answer I accepted did answer my question and is not opinion-based. Although the crash of Arrow Air Flight 1285R is blamed on a multitude of factors, one of the primary reasons is icing and overloading. And although the "overloading" does include luggage, the number and weight of passengers also played a significant role.

Downvoters, can you please tell me how to improve? I mean, this question had been downvoted many times, so I figured there must be something that I can improve. On the other hand, however, the answerers here did a great job at explaining the problem and providing interesting cases and great answers, so I think my question is not completely inscrutable or off-topic. So, if there's any space for improvement, please tell me through the comments and I will try my best. Also, please stop the downvoting if you don't have anything to say.

Maybe not solely, but Yes. A flight carrying a company of US Army 101st Airborne soldiers returning home from the Middle East crashed on takeoff from a refueling stop in Newfoundland because their average weight was much higher than the standard average passenger weight that burocratic standard FAA airline procedures used to calculate aicraft gross weight and takeoff performance.

Thanks for your answer, I'm really interested in this case. Can you please edit your answer to contain information regarding the type of aircraft, flight number, and (if possible) the NTSB's report on the accident?

There was a famous Gander crash that sounds similar to this, Arrow Air Flight 1285R, but that wasn’t the stated cause.

@300D7309EF17 Are you two talking about the same crash? Because I couldn't find any other accidents having the same details: US Marines returning home, crashing in Canada, ... So, Charles Bretana, are you talking about Arrow Air Flight 1285R?

Yes, I am referring to Gander Arrow 1285 crash. Attached below is quote from history doc:

The Canadian Aviation Safety Board's (CASB) extensive investigation of the crash of Arrow flight 1285 is not expected to be completed until early 1987. Preliminary findings indicate that the crash was likely caused by the unfortunate confluence of a number of factors, no one of which would have been sufficient to bring the plane down. These included icing on the wings, mechanical problems, and crew fatigue. Overweight conditions in the passenger compartment due to the large amount of carry-on luggage also might have been a factor.

..... Passenger and carryon luggage weight was not determined prior to take-off at Cairo, but the Arrow flight crew had estimated that the average weight per passenger, including carryon luggage, was 170 pounds. The CASB calculations indicated that the average weight per passenger with carryon luggage was at least 220 pounds.

You can read more here:   https://history.army.mil/books/dahsum/1986/appa.htm

@CharlesBretana Thanks a lot for the added info! Although I knew of this crash earlier, the details you provided really helped me understand the causes of the crash better. Again, thanks!

Yr very welcome!

If you have YouTube, also check out Air Disasters episode on this crash...

Aaliyah's crash in the Bahamas was definitely caused by too many people on the plane. This happens with small piston-powered planes flown by incompetent operators. It does not happen in commercial flights where enforcement of gross weight and CG balance restrictions is part of standard operating procedure.

Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for commercial flights (think Boeing 737, 747, 767, 727, 787,... or at the smallest turboprops like ATR 72) , not chartered Cessna aircraft. I might be looking for some crashes in the old days of aviation, when regulations weren't as strict.

@AircraftEnthusiast007 you should edit the question and title to indicate this.

@300D7309EF17 Thanks for the suggestion, I've already edited my post to reflect what I want.

A chartered aircraft is by definition a "commercial" flight.

@randomhead Yeah, but I stated in my question that I'm looking for crashes involving aircraft with the size of at least turboprops like ATR 72. I hope that is clear enough to understand that Cessna crashes and accidents aren't what I'm looking for. The problem is not "Chartered", it's "Cessna".

Wasn't the CG balance problem caused by an unexpected one ton extra luggages ?

In 2003, Air Midwest Flight 5481 crashed. One of the causes was incorrect calculation of passenger weights. The average was 20lbs low, the plane took off at 105% of its maximum weight.
